# How to read data at the specific coordinates in high-dimensional Mat:class using c++?

Tags: c++, opencv, dotnetnuke

I am trying to use use the MobileNet SSD + deep neural network ( dnn ) module in OpenCV for object detection. I loaded and used the model successfully. As the output of net.forward I obtain Mat object containing the information about the detected objects. Unfortunately, I struggle with "the easy part of work", with reading what exactly was detected.

Here is information I know about the output Mat object:

- It has 4 dimensions.
- The size is 1 x 1 x number_of_objects_detected x 7.
- The seven pieces of information about each object were: the 1st is the class ID, the 2nd is the confidence, the 3rd-7th are the bounding box values.

I can't find any c++ example, but I found many python examples. They read the data like this:

```
for i in np.arange(0, detections.shape[2]):    
    confidence = detections[0, 0, i, 2]
```

What is the easiest way how to do this in c++? I.e. I need to read the data at the specific coordinates in high-dimensional Mat:class.

Thank you for your kind help. I am quite new in c++ and sometimes found it overwhelming...

I am using OpenCV 3.3.0. The GitHub with the MobileNet SSD I am using: https://github.com/chuanqi305/MobileNet-SSD.

The code of my program:

```
#include <opencv2/dnn.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::dnn;

using namespace std;

// function to create vector of class names
std::vector<String> createClaseNames() {
    std::vector<String> classNames;
    classNames.push_back("background");
    classNames.push_back("aeroplane");
    classNames.push_back("bicycle");
    classNames.push_back("bird");
    classNames.push_back("boat");
    classNames.push_back("bottle");
    classNames.push_back("bus");
    classNames.push_back("car");
    classNames.push_back("cat");
    classNames.push_back("chair");
    classNames.push_back("cow");
    classNames.push_back("diningtable");
    classNames.push_back("dog");
    classNames.push_back("horse");
    classNames.push_back("motorbike");
    classNames.push_back("person");
    classNames.push_back("pottedplant");
    classNames.push_back("sheep");
    classNames.push_back("sofa");
    classNames.push_back("train");
    classNames.push_back("tvmonitor");
    return classNames;
}

// main function
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // set inputs
    String modelTxt = "C:/Users/acer/Desktop/kurz_OCV/cv4faces/project/python/object-detection-deep-learning/MobileNetSSD_deploy.prototxt";
    String modelBin = "C:/Users/acer/Desktop/kurz_OCV/cv4faces/project/python/object-detection-deep-learning/MobileNetSSD_deploy.caffemodel";
    String imageFile = "C:/Users/acer/Desktop/kurz_OCV/cv4faces/project/puppies.jpg";
    std::vector<String> classNames = createClaseNames();

    //read caffe model
    Net net;
    try {
        net = dnn::readNetFromCaffe(modelTxt, modelBin);
    }
    catch (cv::Exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        if (net.empty())
        {
            std::cerr << "Can't load network." << std::endl;
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    // read image 
    Mat img = imread(imageFile);

    // create input blob
    resize(img, img, Size(300, 300));
    Mat inputBlob = blobFromImage(img, 0.007843, Size(300, 300), Scalar(127.5)); //Convert Mat to dnn::Blob image batch

    // apply the blob on the input layer
    net.setInput(inputBlob); //set the network input

    // classify the image by applying the blob on the net
    Mat detections = net.forward("detection_out"); //compute output

    // print some information about detections
    std::cout << "dims: " << detections.dims << endl;
    std::cout << "size: " << detections.size << endl;

    //show image
    String winName("image");
    imshow(winName, img);

    // Wait for keypress
    waitKey();

}
```

Comment: There is a C++ sample with MobileNet-SSD from Caffe: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/dnn/ssd_mobilenet_object_detection.cpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the official OpenCV tutorial on [how to scan images](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/db/da5/tutorial_how_to_scan_images.html#gsc.tab=0).

The normal way you'd access a 3-channel (i.e. color) `Mat` way would be using the [`Mat::at()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aa5d20fc86d41d59e4d71ae93daee9726) method of the `Mat` class, which is heavily overloaded for all sorts of accessor options. Specifically, you can send in an [array of indices](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a474bd5cdcf986672cfdc304f6be1cf64) or a [vector of indices](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a9ec1aadc17ab8c8f8334d521719c7732).

---

Here's a most basic example creating a 4D `Mat` and accessing a specific element:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int size[4] = { 2, 2, 5, 7 };
    cv::Mat M(4, size, CV_32FC1, cv::Scalar(1));
    int indx[4] = { 0, 0, 2, 3 };
    std::cout << "M[0, 0, 2, 3] = " << M.at<float>(indx) << std::endl;
}
```

> ```
> M[0, 0, 2, 3] = 1
> ```

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. In fact, I've already tried to us Mat::at() - but it seems to support at most three-dimensional space (https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a305829ed5c0ecfef7b44db18953048e8).
To be concrete, I am just not able to do this:
`int class = detections.at<int>(0, 0, 0, 1);`

Comment: Thank you for the example, know I get it.

Comment: @Beth yeah if you look at all the overloaded definitions of `at()` that are linked in the documentation, you'll see that a max of 3 args is given for 3-D accessing; otherwise you need to use an array or vector for indexing N-D matrices. If this answers your question, would you mind accepting it? Otherwise let me know if it should be expanded.

Answer (score 1):

Someone might find this question in the context of using the MobileNet SSD + deep neural network ( dnn ) module in OpenCV for object detection. So here I post the already functional code of object detection. Alexander Reynolds thank you for your help.

```
#include <opencv2/dnn.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::dnn;
using namespace std;

// function to create vector of class names
std::vector<String> createClaseNames() {
    std::vector<String> classNames;
    classNames.push_back("background");
    classNames.push_back("aeroplane");
    classNames.push_back("bicycle");
    classNames.push_back("bird");
    classNames.push_back("boat");
    classNames.push_back("bottle");
    classNames.push_back("bus");
    classNames.push_back("car");
    classNames.push_back("cat");
    classNames.push_back("chair");
    classNames.push_back("cow");
    classNames.push_back("diningtable");
    classNames.push_back("dog");
    classNames.push_back("horse");
    classNames.push_back("motorbike");
    classNames.push_back("person");
    classNames.push_back("pottedplant");
    classNames.push_back("sheep");
    classNames.push_back("sofa");
    classNames.push_back("train");
    classNames.push_back("tvmonitor");
    return classNames;
}  

// main function
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // set inputs
    String modelTxt = "Path to MobileNetSSD_deploy.prototxt";
    String modelBin = "Path to MobileNetSSD_deploy.caffemodel";
    String imageFile = "Path to test image";
    std::vector<String> classNames = createClaseNames();

    //read caffe model
    Net net;
    try {
        net = dnn::readNetFromCaffe(modelTxt, modelBin);
    }
    catch (cv::Exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        if (net.empty())
        {
            std::cerr << "Can't load network." << std::endl;
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    // read image 
    Mat img = imread(imageFile);
    Size imgSize = img.size();

    // create input blob
    Mat img300;
    resize(img, img300, Size(300, 300));
    Mat inputBlob = blobFromImage(img300, 0.007843, Size(300, 300), Scalar(127.5)); //Convert Mat to dnn::Blob image batch

    // apply the blob on the input layer
    net.setInput(inputBlob); //set the network input

    // classify the image by applying the blob on the net
    Mat detections = net.forward("detection_out"); //compute output

    // look what the detector found
    for (int i=0; i < detections.size[2]; i++) {

        // print information into console
        cout << "-----------------" << endl;
        cout << "Object nr. " << i + 1 << endl;

        // detected class
        int indxCls[4] = { 0, 0, i, 1 };
        int cls = detections.at<float>(indxCls);
        std::cout << "class: " << classNames[cls] << endl;

        // confidence
        int indxCnf[4] = { 0, 0, i, 2 };
        float cnf = detections.at<float>(indxCnf);
        std::cout << "confidence: " << cnf * 100 << "%" << endl;

        // bounding box
        int indxBx[4] = { 0, 0, i, 3 };
        int indxBy[4] = { 0, 0, i, 4 };
        int indxBw[4] = { 0, 0, i, 5 };
        int indxBh[4] = { 0, 0, i, 6 };
        int Bx = detections.at<float>(indxBx) * imgSize.width;
        int By = detections.at<float>(indxBy) * imgSize.height;
        int Bw = detections.at<float>(indxBw) * imgSize.width - Bx;
        int Bh = detections.at<float>(indxBh) * imgSize.height - By;
        std::cout << "bounding box [x, y, w, h]: " << Bx << ", " << By << ", " << Bw << ", " << Bh << endl;

        // draw bounding box to image
        Rect bbox(Bx, By, Bw, Bh);
        rectangle(img, bbox, Scalar(255,0,255),1,8,0);

    }
    //show image
    String winName("image");
    imshow(winName, img);

    // Wait for keypress
    waitKey();

}
```